# GridBagLayout - Unintended added/and changed spacing

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

So, I have a problem with the changed spacing between panels (containing `JTextAreas`) when I add panels, see this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiCuY.png). :D

[image]

### Example

When a button is pressed the first time `addTextArea()` is called. State 1 -> state 2 in the picture. And the problem is that the panel_buttons isn't as close to the newly added `WorkDescription` (`JTextArea`). And when the button is pressed multiple times, the spacing between them change.

The buttons did a big jump before, but with;  `c.weighty = 0.1 - 0.3` the jump is smaller.

```
// The panel is placed in the center of a JFrame (BorderLayout)
public CONSTRUCTOR {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    // ...
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    // this is how everything looks at (first pic) start.
    panel.add(panel_buttons, c);   // panel_buttons is at the right place
}
```

The method that adds a new `WorkDescription`, namely a `JTextArea`:

```
public void addTextArea() {

    WorkDescription wd = new WorkDescription(); //WorkDescription extends JPanel

    panel.remove(panel_buttons); 
    c.weighty = 0.25;       // I've messed around with the weighty alot.
                            // 0.2-0.25 makes the panel_buttons do the least amout of 'down-jump'
    panel.add(wd, c);

    if(c.gridy < 3 ) {
        c.gridy ++;
        c.weighty = 1;

        panel.add(panel_buttons, c);
    }
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
}
```

Comment: I'm rather new to StackOverFlow, and programming for that matter.. Is the question clear? :)

Comment: Please edit the question and make it [mcve].

Comment: I have now updated :D

Comment: Layout constraints (e.g. `GridBagConstraints`) are NOT meant to be "dynamic" (atleast 90% of the time). So, avoid using them in your program logic. Use them to build "static" UIs.

Comment: Alright! Which layout would you recommend for dynamic?

Comment: What I meant is "all" layout "constraints" are suppose to be "static". (means we should not change the constraints frequently.) Of course, the size and position of components will change when user resize the window.

Comment: Okey, thing is the problem is way more severe if the weighty is static .. :/

Comment: Also, the window is not resizeable. And if weighty is the same, the panel_buttons doesn't seem to follow the [ c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST; ]

Comment: 1) *"I have now updated"* O..K, but note that the question right now still has no [mcve] of your current attempt. If we can't copy/paste compile/run with absolutely **no changes,** it's not an MCVE. 2) Often GUIs are achieved by combining layouts in different parts of what the user sees as 1 GUI. Each layout relevant to that part of the GUI. There is no 'best layout' but simply 'the best layout(s) for the job'. 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: Thank you for the edit Andrew!

Comment: Switch from GridBagLayout to GridLayout worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best **solution** I found was to,

Switch from `GridBagLayout` to `GridLayout`.

```
private JPanel panel_Center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
```

And then, of course, remove all `GridBagConstraints`

```
public void addTextArea() {

    WorkDescription wd = new WorkDescription();

    panel.remove(panel_buttons); 
    panel.add(wd);

    if(addedWorks < 4 ) {       

        addedWorks++;
        panel.add(panel_buttons);

    }

    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
}
```